# Which one is idiomatic - at a restaurant - after the waiter brought the food and put them on the table: "The food has arrived" or "The food has come."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, idiomatic-language

You are at a restaurant, you order and wait for some time for the food. Then, the waiter comes and brings the food you ordered. Then he leaves and you say:

**1-The food has arrived.**

**2-The food has come.**

Which one is idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.  It's pretty obvious to your partner that the food has been served. You might say "let's eat" or "enjoy your meal" or something.

If you are phoning your friend who is not in the restaurant then I suppose you could use a phrase like this.

"Arrived" or "come" mean the same, so both sentences are grammatically correct and idiomatic, but it would be better to say "The food has been served", or "the food is here."

> {on phone, leaving a message}  Hi, I'm at the restaurant and the food has just {come, arrived, been served}.  I ordered the chilli for you.  Let me know when you're going to get here.